# Application of MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I was reading about the concept of MLE as to how parameters of a particular assumed distribution are calculated using the MLE approach. But, I wonder what is done next once the value of the parameters with the best possible value is/are calculated. I mean what to do next once the MLE is calculated? How, is it utilized over a new set of points, etc.
For an example say I have a set of data points. Let's denote it by D. By looking at the data and prior experience, I assume Gaussian distribution and try to find out mean and variance. I successfully found those values. Now, the question is how should I use the model data that is available with me?
Any piece of advice would be helpful. If there are post related to this question then, I request you to please provide the link about the same.

Comment: MLE is a broad topic, useful for many families of distributions. Do you have a particular example or distribution in mind? You seem to be stuck at "what next?" but give no clue what next toward what end?

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for pointing out the problem in the post. I have updated it. I think this should help you or any other person answer my question with a little ease.

Comment: What you might do next after computing some MLE depends on what you're trying to achieve. It might be any number of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now we know you're interested in MLEs for normal data. But your goal in
finding these estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ might be. Maybe if I give
a couple of examples, that might help you to refine your question.

Suppose you know that scores on the ABC college entrance exam for this year
are normally distributed with mean $\mu = 350$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 50.$ You have 100 early applications for your college with sample mean $\bar X = 360$ and sample SD $S = 56.$ These sample statistics are based on MLEs.

**Estimating average scores.** You want to know whether the applicants so
far might be better than the population mean. So you do a one-sample t test
of the  null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 350$ against $H_a: \mu > 350.$ The
procedure for one-sample t tests is explained in most elementary statistics
texts. Output from Minitab statistical software for such a test on your
data is as follows:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 350 vs > 350

  N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean  95% Lower Bound     T      P
100  360.00  56.00     5.60           350.70  1.79  0.039
```

Because the P-value is below 0.05, we say that the sample mean $\bar X = 360$ is significantly larger than the population mean $\mu = 350$ at the 5% level
of significance.

**Estimating proportion of qualifying scores.** Maybe your college only admits students with ABC scores of 410 or above.
Among the 100 applications at hand, how many have sufficiently high scores?
You may find that there are 15 of them, and estimate that you are on track for 15% of applicants
to qualify. But the fraction of sufficiently high scores among the 100
is ***not based on MLEs.*** So this is not the best way to estimate this year's
proportion of qualified students. [We see below that this estimate is to low. Using the number of qualifying scores among the 100 at hand might just as well have given an estimate that is too high.]

*Using the MLEs,* we ask what proportion of a normal population with mean 360 and SD 56 would have qualifying scores. According to a quick computation in R
statistical software, that turns out to be about 19%. *This is a better estimate because the MLEs carry more information about your applications on hand than
does the actual count of qualifying applications.*

```
1-pnorm(409.4, 360, 56)
[1] 0.1888498
```

*Note:* it would also be a mistake to look at the proportion of qualifying ABC scores
nationwide because that would be only about 12%.

```
1 - pnorm(409.5, 350, 50)
[1] 0.1170232
```

**Addendum.** A million samples of size $n=100$ were taken from
$\mathsf{Norm}(350, 50).$ The population 88th percentile is 408.75.
For each sample of 100 the 88th percentile was estimated by taking
the 88th sample percentile (`sp.88`). Also, the 88th population 
percentile (`pp.88`) was found for the distribution estimated using MLEs
$\mathsf{Norm}(\bar X, S).$ The histograms show that the MLE method
is nearly unbiased and has smaller variance than the sample percentile method.

[image]

R code for the simulation (but not the histogram) is shown below.

```
set.seed(920)
mu = 350; sg = 50; n = 100
m = 10^6; sp.88 = pp.88 = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  x = rnorm(n,mu,sg)
  sp.88[i] = quantile(x,.88)
  pp.88[i] = qnorm(.88,mean(x),sd(x)) }
mean(sp.88); sd(sp.88)
[1] 407.65
[1] 7.979684  ## larger SD
mean(pp.88); sd(pp.88)
[1] 408.5956  ## closer to 408.75
[1] 6.509124  ## smaller SD
```